# Explaining BERT output through SHAP values without WordPiece tokenization

Tags: tokenize, bert-language-model, shap

I fine-tuned BERT on a sentiment analysis task in PyTorch.
Now I want to use SHAP to explain which tokens led the model to the prediction (positive or negative sentiment).

Currently, SHAP returns a value for each WordPiece (e.g. 'lovely' == 'love', '##ly').
Is it possible to feed pre-tokenized sentences to SHAP and disable to BERT tokenization?

My code:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased', do_lower_case=True)
# model is the loaded fine-tuned model, based on bert-base-multilingual-cased)

def predictor(x):
    outputs = model(**tokenizer(x, return_tensors="pt", padding=True))
    probas = F.softmax(outputs, dim=1).detach().numpy()
    val = sp.special.logit(probas[:,1])
    return val

def f_batch(x):
    val = np.array([])
    for i in x:
      val = np.append(val, predictor(i))
    return val

explainer_bert = shap.Explainer(f_batch, tokenizer)
test = {'label': [1], 'text': ['this is a lovely movie']}

shap_values = explainer_bert(test, fixed_context=1)
shap.plots.text(shap_values)
```

[image]

Also, I am aware of this paper: https://aclanthology.org/2021.hackashop-1.3.pdf
But I was wondering if there was a simpler way.